# I want to create a timer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to windows programming and have the following code that will show the current time:

```
string str = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
string[] str1=str.Split(' ');
label5.Text = str1[0];
label3.Text = str1[1];
```

In the code, the label fields are simply set by parsing the current time.

This is great, however, I need my form to refresh and, in real-time, update the current time.

The clock should update on a per-second interval and be started and stopped by pressing button controls.

Comment: drag a `timer` from toolbox into your form if you use Visual Studio. then use timer's events.

Comment: Thanks @BehnamSafari Sir,I got my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timer_tick);
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    label3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

Comment: Does it need attaching to a window?

Comment: Yes I have missed something. Now code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Timer control to your form and set it to 1000 milisecs. Then add two buttons (start and stop) and this should work

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date = date.AddSeconds(1);
    label1.Text = date.ToString("mm:ss");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}
```